# Advanced Custom Field Content doesn't show in wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm having a bit of trouble getting acf content to show within the Wordpress loop.
The code I'm using within the page.php template is as follows:

```
<?php $args = array (
'post_type' => 'test-box'
);
$the_query = new wp_query ( $args);
?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query-   >the_post(); ?>

<?php 
the_field( 'acf_test_box_header' );
the_field( 'acf_test_box_content' );
?>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>

<p>There are no posts to display.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is that the two fields: acf_test_box_header and acf_test_box_content don't display their content when inside the loop, returning instead 'header 2' and 'content 2'. If I move them outside the loop then they display the content as it was entered fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe try this the_field( 'acf_test_box_header', get_the_ID ()) ?

Comment: Your if statement is not correct.
`if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :`

Comment: Nope - not making any difference sadly.

Comment: Similarly, with the_query modified, still the same :-(

Comment: Maybe this:
`$current_id = get_the_ID(); 
the_field( 'acf_test_box_content', $current_id );`

Comment: Bingo! It worked :-) If you put it there as an answer will do an accept and mark it up - cheers ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$current_id = get_the_ID(); 
the_field( 'acf_test_box_content', $current_id );
```